# access and query DbSet of DbContext by name

Tags: entity-framework, dbset

how to access and query a DbSet of DbContext by name (passing a string with the entity name or the fullname)

something like (but this doesn't work)

```
string myTypeName= "mycustomtype";   //or  "mynamespace1.mynamespace2.mycustomtype"  
Type myType = Type.GetType(myTypeName);
var dbset = db.Set(myType);

// i can't query dbset
//i should do something like this (but i don't know how to do it)
var result = ((IEnumerable<myType>)db.Set(myType)).toList();
```

Answer (score 0):

@alex,

I've spent a lot of time on this. I could not find a way as simple as your metacode in the question. **I am welcome to improvements on the below.**

My need may not be the same as yours, so let me explain:

1. It is easy to create a class instance by a string. There are lots of examples here on SO.
2. What is NOT easy (I'm pretty sure) is how to create an instance of a class that you can simply add with your context:

`ctx.SomeModels.Add(myClass);`

...that will work with:

```
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

3. I found that the class in play had to come from the DbContext in order for it to accept it back, or even to use in a Delete()...

If this matches your scenario, this might help.

Notes:
-I have removed all my logging (with NLog), which adds a lot of debugging, but makes this harder to read.
-If you make a few Breakpoints and look at the values & choices, you will see some things I had to correct for.
 
-There are 2 parts to the problem:
1. Finding the assembly's version of the name of the class from a simple one.
2. Using that computer-friendly name to make a class that would make DbContext not complain:

```
/****************************************************************
 * 
 * CreateInstanceOf
 *     DbTableName = SOMETHINGS <--- note pluralization
 *     BaseAssembly = Assembly for your calling project-NOT this DLL 
 *     (if this is in a dll)...
 * 
 * This method is given a table name (plural), and returns an instance 
 *     of that Model' class (singular)... Failing that, returns null.
 */
public object CreateInstanceOf(string DbTableName, Assembly BaseAssembly)
{
    string className = String.Empty;
    string baseClassName = String.Empty;
    string trimmedClassName = String.Empty;
    string qualifiedAssemblyName = String.Empty;
    try
    {
        /**********************
         * 
         * Part 1 - just get the details on a matching class... 
         *
         */
        foreach (var t in BaseAssembly.GetTypes())
        {
            if (((String)t.Namespace == null) || (!t.Namespace.Contains("Models"))) // adjust to suit (I'm in MVC here)
            {
                // Type is not in Models namespace... skipping
                continue; // just looking for classes in the Models namespace (MVC)
            }
            foreach (var cat in t.CustomAttributes)
            {
                foreach (var car in cat.ConstructorArguments)
                {
                    if (car != null)
                    {
                        t.Name, cat.ToString(), car.ToString());
                        char[] charsToTrim = { '"', ' ' }; // weird how there are actual quotes in the string...
                        string trimmedCar = car.ToString().Trim(charsToTrim); 
                        if (trimmedCar == DbTableName)
                        {
                            // we have a winner!
                            qualifiedAssemblyName = t.AssemblyQualifiedName;
                            baseClassName = trimmedCar;
                            trimmedClassName = (t.Namespace + "." + trimmedCar).Trim(charsToTrim);
                            break;
                        } else
                        {
                            // nothing to see here, move along...
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        /**********************
         * 
         * Part 2 - create the class with this info... 
         *
         */
        if ((trimmedClassName != null) && (trimmedClassName.Length > 0))
        {
            Type tipe = Type.GetType(qualifiedAssemblyName);
            AssemblyName an = BaseAssembly.GetName();
            char[] charsToTrim = { '"', ' ' };
            string trimmedManModName = BaseAssembly.ManifestModule.Name.ToString().Trim(charsToTrim);
            var result = Activator.CreateInstance(
                tipe
                );
            return result;
        } else
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I read your code twice but nothing found for answer @alex question...Could you please say What we should exactly?

Comment: This code creates an object of the type named, which can be queried. Try it.